# Full screen Silverlight with keyboard input

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, silverlight-5.0

I'm currently extending a Silverlight app that has some data integration with a bespoke programming language. The app has a full screen mode but we not have edit boxes and need the keyboard input in full screen mode. The current app sits in-browser in a central panel with navigation controls etc on either side.

So far i've looked at the following:

1. Creating a set of pages with a master pages with no panels on either side and then 'switching' to use this master page when going full screen. The intention here was to have a larger client area to draw the map so it was drawn within the full browser page. Because of the chain of dependencies and layers of inheritance I've had to abandon this idea.
2. A full trust application. This sounded ideal but then I can't set the needed registry key on the client machines (they can access the app from anywhere).
3. Currently looking at client side javascript to 'hide' the panels on either side of the map and then draw the map in the full browser window. Ongoing.

Apart from the on-screen keyboard that the client does not like are there any other options ?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never :-)

In the end I went for Option 3 which was quite easy to implement and drew the map within the client area of the browser. The client now wants to the whole map app to be rewritten in JS (as they have heard SL is being binned in 5 or 6 years).